# Font Sizing Per Device Programmatically

Tags: swift, uilabel, uifont

I am attempting to alter the text of a `UILabel` such that the text looks exactly the same per device.

[image: Label texts]

Here, I have 4 different simulators: `8Plus, 7, 5s, XR` in that order. As you can see the texts look different. On the first simulation, it's smaller than say the 3rd one. How can I make it scale and look the same for each device, i.e. the text respects the size of the box?

```
let label = UILabel(frame: button.bounds)
    label.text = "Done"
    label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.2
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.textColor = .white
    label.font = UIFont(name: label.font.fontName, size: 20)
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On the first simulation, it's smaller than say the 3rd one.

No, it isn't. It just looks like that because screen of iPhone 5S (640x1136 points) is smaller then screen of let's say iPhone Xs (1125x2436). Also text looks small against its background since background has fixed constraints which cause its resizing on all devices.

In order your text looked similarly against its background on all screens, you would have to set `UILabel`'s top, leading, bottom and trailing constraint equal to superview's (with custom constant)

[image]

... then as you did, set `minimumScaleFactor` for your label

So, if you set *font size* to 20, then *maximum* font size will be 20. If your label *should be smaller* (there wouldn't be enough space because of constraints you set), your label will have *the biggest possible* font size which you set as minimum scale factor.

Comment: I don't want a label text to look normal text for iPhone XR and look MASSIVE for iPhone 5s. What is the best appropriate action for this? Or is this normal?

Comment: @impression7vx if you just set frame of your label as button's bounds, there would be nothing which would limited your label so it's text will have size which you set. You have to set its constraints as I explained in my answer in order to limit label size and then it's text's font size.

Comment: How would I know the correct constraints so that the font looks the same scalar for every device?

Comment: @impression7vx you have to know what "spacing" you need between your label and superview (in your case button). Co if you want to have "spacing" 5 points, set constant of constraints to 5...

Comment: I'll play with this. Thanks for this :)